# Is this derivation of the general solution to a 2nd order homogenous linear ODE with constant coefficients with a repeated root correct?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

If we have a 2nd order homogenous linear ODE with constant coefficients in the form:

$$ay''+by'+cy=0$$

then the characteristic equation is:

$$a\lambda{}^2+b\lambda{}+c=0$$

Solving the characteristic equation for $\lambda$ we obtain the quadratic formula:

$$\lambda=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

Now if $b^2-4ac>0$ there are two solutions for $\lambda$, namely:

$$\lambda_1=p+q,\quad\lambda_2=p-q$$

where $p=-b/(2a)$ and $q=\sqrt{b^2-4ac}/(2a)$. The general solution to the original ODE can then be shown to be:

$$y=e^{px}[K_1\cosh(qx)+K_2\sinh(qx)]$$

where $K_1$ and $K_2$ are arbitrary constants. Now in the limit as $q\rightarrow{}0$ (with $x$ fixed) we have:

$$\cosh(qx)\rightarrow{}1\\\sinh(qx)\rightarrow{}qx$$

For any two arbitrary constants $C_1$ and $C_2$ let $K_1=C_1$ and $K_2=C_2/q$. It follows that in the limit as $q\rightarrow{}0$ (with $x$ fixed) we have:

$$y=e^{px}\left(C_1*1+\frac{C_2}{q}*qx\right)=e^{px}(C_1+C_2x)$$

which is the general solution to the original ODE in the case when $b^2-4ac=0$.

Similarly, if $b^2-4ac<0$ there are two solutions for $\lambda$, namely:

$$\lambda_1=p+iq,\quad\lambda_2=p-iq$$

where $p=-b/(2a)$ and $q=\sqrt{4ac-b^2}/(2a)$. The general solution to the original ODE can then be shown to be:

$$y=e^{px}[K_1\cos(qx)+K_2\sin(qx)]$$

where $K_1$ and $K_2$ are arbitrary constants. Now in the limit as $q\rightarrow{}0$ (with $x$ fixed) we have:

$$\cos(qx)\rightarrow{}1\\\sin(qx)\rightarrow{}qx$$

For any two arbitrary constants $C_1$ and $C_2$ let $K_1=C_1$ and $K_2=C_2/q$. It follows that in the limit as $q\rightarrow{}0$ (with $x$ fixed) we have:

$$y=e^{px}\left(C_1*1+\frac{C_2}{q}*qx\right)=e^{px}(C_1+C_2x)$$

which again is the general solution to the original ODE in the case when $b^2-4ac=0$.

Is this derivation of the solution to this ODE in the case of a repeated root correct? If so, why isn't this simple derivation more commonly taught in textbooks, at least as an alternative approach to the common variation of parameters approach?